# How to use the TabActivity Menu without interference with the children tabs

Tags: android, android-menu, android-tabactivity

This topic can look similar to others but I haven't found any usable answer for this case.

Here is what I want : I have a `TabActivity` with a menu, containing tabs without any menu. When I press the menu button, I want the only existing menu to be displayed. If I only inflate the menu, this is working fine. But if I want to change the content of the menu (change the visibility of items in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)` method) or even press the items of the menu, nothing works.

For the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)`, the problem seems to be coming from the `menu.findItem(...)` method which returns a null Object, and I have a `NullPointerException` !
In `onOptionsItemSelected(item)`, none of the item IDs will be recognized.

I have noticed with the debugger that the menu Context is the activity of the current tab, so I have moved the menu inside of that activity instead, but without more success.

Last thing, I was using the same menu and very similar code in a previous version of the app, using a single activity (no tabs) and I didn't encounter any problem. When I moved to the TabActivity design it was first working fine (maybe the context of the menu was my `TabActivity` instead of the `Activity` of the tab), but it didn't work anymore after minor changes to the Activities of the tabs (nothing related to any menu).

If you think using `ActionBar` (and the support package) would fix this, I am already planning in moving to it later, but I would like to understand and fix this first.

Here is the code :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem connect1 = menu.findItem(R.id.connect_1);
    MenuItem connect2 = menu.findItem(R.id.connect_2);

    // Here I do some stuff to prepare the menu, which could be simplified
    // like this :
    if (device1Connected)
        if (!connect1.isVisible()) // here I get the NullPointerException
            connect1.setVisible(true);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.select_device:
        // do some stuff
        return true;
    case R.id.connect_1:
        // do some stuff
        return true;
    case R.id.connect_2:
        // do some stuff
        return true;
    case R.id.disconnect:
        // do some stuff
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the XML file of the menu, nothing special

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/select_device"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:title="@string/choose_devices"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/connect_1"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
          android:title="@string/connect_1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/connect_2"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
          android:title="@string/connect_2" />
    <item android:id="@+id/disconnect"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
          android:title="@string/disconnect" />
</menu>
```

**Edit :** I have added the following in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)` to avoid the NullPointerException. It doesn't fix the real problem but I can now see precisely what happens when I click on a `MenuItem`

```
if (connect1 == null || connect2 == null)
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
```

When I click on the first item, `getItemId()` returns, for example, **2131165207**, and the second item returns **2131165208** (I have checked, they are ids of `Views` of the second tab !!), but the values it should return to enter the switch/case are respectively **2131165215** and **2131165216**, so as I said before, I have a problem with my item ids. I made this test with the menu within the `Activity` of the first tab, because the `mContext` value of the **menu** is always an instance of the current Activity. But even though the Context AND the Activity containing the menu are the same, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ! I have finally figured out what was wrong. It was a building/compiling error. I have been trying before refreshing the project many time, but it was not enough, I had also tried deleting the `R.java` file (where are compiling the ID numbers from the XML files), but it still didn't work; and I finally remembered about the `Project -> Clear...` function in Eclipse while working on another project.

And it just worked. So that was nothing there very challenging, but at least I've learnt something valuable today.